# ASP.NET Core on Linux with massive performance problems using EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have written a web application with ASP.NET Core MVC using Entity Framework Core with SQL Server 2016. Everything runs fine performance wise as long as I host the website on Windows (IIS).

Recently I tried to publish the app to my Root Server running Centos 7.3 with SQL Server 2016 (v.Next CTP 1.4) and .net core 1.1.

Sadly, the following code causes major trouble:

```
return _context.StockData
            .Include(i => i.Stock).ThenInclude(i => i.StockIndex)
            .Where(w => w.Date == date)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToList();
```

- Windows 10 + MSSQL (remote on Root-Server): **36 ms**
- Centos 7.3 + MSSQL (local on Root-Server):  **40 sec** (!)

*Note*: Table *StockData* has about 120k rows, table *Stock* has about 1k rows and *StockIndex* has only 10 rows

**SQL Profiler**
[image: SQL Profiler]
The first 2 requests are from the Win10 client, the last 2 queries are from the root server running on linux.

It seems like the time is not lost on the db query itself but while "parsing" the db result into the appropriate c# objects. Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

Thanks!

Steven

Comment: Have you run it with a profiler? There are DNX profilers that run on Linux - they would indicate where exactly inside EF the performance hit is.

Comment: We have production environments with asp net core on linux and no performance issues. Have you checked the response time between your linux machine and the database server?

Comment: The linux machine hosts both - the database and the web app. So the linux web app accesses the local database, so there is no network latency.

Comment: Is the executed SQL the same on both environments?

Comment: Yes, the query is exactly the same. SQL Profiler shows both queries with the same CPU cost and reads. Also the execution time for both queries is at about 40ms, according to the database profiler. So my guess is, the time must be "lost" on creating the C# objects from the db results